# Add string from file to filename

Tags: bash, filenames, string

I need to rename files to include a string found in the first line.

**ex:**

```
[acoder@test]# head -1 FILE001.DAT
XYZ123
```

Here's my best guess:

```
for file in /some/dir/*.DAT
do
        CODE=`head -1 "$file"`
        echo "${file%.DAT}.$CODE.DAT"
done
```

**output:**

```
.DATa/some/dir/FILE001.XYZ123
```

**expecting to see:**

```
/some/dir/FILE001.XYZ123.DAT
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Is there a carriage-return (`\r` or `^M`) at the end of the line in the file? Try `cat -v FILE001.DAT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file comes from a Windows system, it may have a carriage-return at the end.

You can fix that by assigning to the `CODE` variable like this:

```
CODE="$( head -n 1 "$file" | tr -d '\r' )"
```